# Unable to build the HTML Structure into JSP using scriptlets

Tags: java

I have the following HTML accordian structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Basic jQuery Accordion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3",          
                    autoheight: false,
                    active: false,
                    alwaysOpen: false,
                    fillspace: false,
                    collapsible: true,
                    //heightStyle: content   //auto, fill, content
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <div style="width: 468px;">
        <div id="accordion">

            <h3><a href="#">Javascript</a></h3>
            <div>
                <h4>Testt</h4>
             </div>


            <h3><a href="#">Other</a></h3>
            <div>
                <h4>Stuff</h4>
            </div>




        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**I am trying to build this in a jsp file as shown**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Basic jQuery Accordion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3",          
                    autoheight: false,
                    active: false,
                    alwaysOpen: false,
                    fillspace: false,
                    collapsible: true,
                    //heightStyle: content   //auto, fill, content
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <div style="width: 468px;">
        <div id="accordion">

        <%
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("CoolDrinks");
        list.add("Snacks");
        list.add("Other");
        %>


                <%
                for (String items : list)
                {
                    %>
                     <h3><a href="#"><%=items%></a></h3>
                     <div>
                         <h4><%=items%></h4>
                      </div>
                <%
                }
                %>
                <%
                }
                %>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anybody please tell me where its failing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import for ArrayList?

`<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>`

EDIT: Upon testing you will also need to remove the last set of:

```
 <%
        }
 %>
```

So it will look like this:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Basic jQuery Accordion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3",          
                    autoheight: false,
                    active: false,
                    alwaysOpen: false,
                    fillspace: false,
                    collapsible: true,
                    //heightStyle: content   //auto, fill, content
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 468px;">
        <div id="accordion">
            <%
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("CoolDrinks");
            list.add("Snacks");
            list.add("Other");
            %>

            <%
            for (String items : list)
            {
            %>
            <h3><a href="#"><%=items%></a></h3>
            <div>
                <h4><%=items%></h4>
            </div>
            <%
            }
            %>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start your page with jsp header :

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>        
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
....
```